# Does vuforia supports dynamic models. Add, Remove, Change models to be tracked during runtime

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia, vuforia-cloud-recognition

I don't have much knowledge about the Vuforia AR

I have made one sample AR app using Vuforia with Unity that uses ImageTargets. In that I have attached some Images in the Vuforia developer portal and downloaded that database file into my project mapped with Image Target and while focusing that image 3d model appears.

**My Question is:**

> 1.Can we create a Image/Model Targets that to be tracked
> in the runtime?**
>
> 2.Also I have list of 3d models that to be displayed dynamically based on the Image/Model targets that can be interchanged between tracking .Is this possible?

Comment: No, afaik that's impossible! You can however enable and disable targets in order to only track the enabled one(s). Sounds like [VuMarks](https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Training/VuMark) would be interresting for you ...

Comment: @derHugo okay thanks a lot. Is there any official link from Vuforia

Answer (score 1):

It is to late response, but anyway. You can add new image targets dynamically by using "[Vuforia Web Services API](https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Solution/How-To-Use-the-Vuforia-Web-Services-API.htm#How-To-Add-a-Target)" and "[Vuforia Cloud Database](https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Solution/How-To-Work-with-Cloud-Databases.html)" This API is simple to use and documentation fully describes how to do this, if you not familiar with REST API's just google for it, but even if you will able to add dynamically new image targets, there is still problem how to add a prefab (augmentation e.g. a 3D model or anything you like) to this target.